# SQL: I need help normalising

Tags: database-normalization

I need help in normalising the following table shown below. I keep getting repeated values when trying to assign a staff to a service.

[image: original orders and services table UN-normalized]

The following are the tables after I normalised.

[image: Tables after normalisation]

I split the staff column from the table. I also removed the `serviceId` and `serviceName` columns and made a new table called `Services`

Comment: You need to use better grammar to be taken seriously. Your title screams "down vote me" because you have two and arguably three grammatical issues in just a five word phrase. This is your first post and visit to the site so I've just edited the grammar for you instead of down voting... See this for reference http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322657/how-to-treat-bad-english-sentence-syntax-and-typo-hell?cb=1

Comment: thanks a lot i will take that into consideration

Comment: Normalization does not introduce new column names (eg ids).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your SOMETHING_ID are PK

Services_Table contains:

- ServiceId PK
- ServiceName

Staff_Table contains:

- StaffID PK
- StaffName

Orders_Table:

- OrderId PK
- ....

Order_Service could be :

- OrderId (FK-Orders_Table)
- ServiceID

Since Order and Service is One-to-Many relationship

Order_Staff could be:

- OrderID (FK-Order_Table)
- StaffID

Since Order staff is One-to-Many relation

Comment: i don't understand something here.for the Orders_Table what are the remaining columns? the    Foreign key  for the Order_Staff table is  a table(Order_Table )?

Comment: (dot dot dot) means any other fields that you want.....Since the relation between the OrderID and Services is a Many-to-One relation, therefore separating Order and Services was needed.......Order_Table could have Order related data like OrderDateTime, OrderStatus,basically anything that you want, that is relevant to your project.

Comment: OrderID(FK) in Order_Staff and Order_Service is the OrderID(PK) in Order_Table.